# Get JSON returned from PHP ADO connection to MS-Access DB

Tags: php, json, ms-access

I'm trying to get JSON string returned from MS-Access DB Query. I get the recordset ($rs) fine, but trying to loop through to return JSON, without knowing all the fields in recordset. The following returns what I want but in `[["aaa":"bbb","ccc":"ddd"]]` not the `[{ ... }]` i'm looking for.

```
    $num_columns = $rs->Fields->Count ();
//echo $num_columns . "<br>";

$arrColumns = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
    $arrColumns[] = $rs->Fields($i);
}

$arrResult = array();

while (!$rs->EOF) {
    $arrRow = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
        $arrRow[] = $arrColumns[$i]->value;
    }
    $arrResult[] = $arrRow;
    $rs->MoveNext();
}
//var_dump($arrResult);
echo json_encode($arrResult);
//print_r($arrResult);
```

[UPDATE]:

accomplished the dynamic part but still have issue with results. Since i'm  `json_encode($Array)` i'm not able to get results with my JQuery as I would like.

```
$num_columns = $rs->Fields->Count ();
$arrColumns = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
    $arrColumns[] = $rs->Fields($i);
    $newArr[] = $rs->Fields($i)->name; 
}

$arrResult = array();

while (!$rs->EOF) {
    $arrRow = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
       $arrRow[$newArr[$i]] = $arrColumns[$i]->value;
    }
    $arrResult[] = $arrRow;

    $rs->MoveNext();
}

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($arrResult) . ')';
```

My JSON gets returned like: `[{"First":"John"},{"Last":"Doe"}]`
An array wrapped in an object. I need to return either an object or an array so I can handle in my client side like: `{"First":"John"},{"Last":"Doe"}`

```
    <script>
        $.getJSON('http://remote.domain.com/json.php?callback=?',function(res){
            alert('Results: '+res.Last);
        });
    </script>
```

I think it might be the way I'm `json_encode($Array);` and not using a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return in the `[{...}]` format, you will need to change the `$arrRow` value from array into class. To make it simple, you can leverage the use of [`stdClass()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

Try something like this:

```
while (!$rs->EOF) {
    $arrRow = array();

    $class = new stdClass();
    $class->field1 = $arrColumns[1]->value;
    $class->field2 = $arrColumns[2]->value;

    $arrRow[] = $arrColumns[$i]->value;

    $arrResult[] = $arrRow;
    $rs->MoveNext();
}

echo json_encode($arrResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this will fix the JSON object issue I was overlooking, but I'm still trying to generate the results dynamically without having to create each Column manually.

Comment: It seems the first part of my code returns the Column name as an object. I'm not able to cast it to a string or get it into a string array? it seems the $arrColumns[] = $rs->Fields($i); puts an object in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You not not have it in `[["aaa":"bbb","ccc":"ddd"]]`  because its not a valid `json` array format ... see [JSON.ORG](http://www.json.org/) for specification

array should be represented as

[image]

While Objects

[image]

The closet you can have is has array is

```
[["aaa","bbb"]["ccc","ddd"]]
```